# Eclipse, Tomcat 7 NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, tomcat7

Trying to run a program in Eclipse on Tomcat 7.0.12 and I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: and
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: and
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

I have no clue what could be causing this.

Comment: Probably you have some error in the configuration: `class: and` missing!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install the troublesome program to a folder without spaces in the full name.